# R lubridate: How to put a lubridate timestamp in a dataframe?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am simply trying to store `lubridate` timestamps in a dataframe. However, they get converted in number of seconds.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)

tsta <- ymd_hms('2021-03-16 22:59:59') # tsta for timestamp

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=1, nrow=2)) # preallocate a small dataframe
colnames(df) <- 'timestamp'

# trying to add lubridate object in it
df[1, 'timestamp'] <- tsta
```

So `tsta` looks like `"2021-03-16 22:59:59 UTC"`, but once I put it in `df` it looks like

```
   timestamp
1 1615935599
2         NA
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix` can store only a single class and `POSIXct` can get converted to its numeric storage values.  One option is

```
df <- tibble(timestamp = c(tsta, ymd_hms(NA)))
```

-output

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  timestamp          
  <dttm>             
1 2021-03-16 22:59:59
2 NA
```

---

Or another way is

```
df <- tibble(timestamp =  ymd_hms(rep(NA, 2)))
df$timestamp[1] <- tsta
df
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  timestamp          
  <dttm>             
1 2021-03-16 22:59:59
2 NA
```

---

Or using the OP's code, the `NA` values are converted first

```
df$timestamp <- ymd_hms(df$timestamp)
df[1, 'timestamp'] <- tsta
df
            timestamp
1 2021-03-16 22:59:59
2                <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks. Pre-allocating my empty column as `ymd_hms(NA)` indeed solved my issue. It doesn't freak out later that I try to put lubridate timestamps in it.

Answer (score 2):

You might save as character data that could be converted to posixct later.

```
tsta <- format(ymd_hms('2021-03-16 22:59:59'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


df[1, 'timestamp'] <- tsta
df
           timestamp
1 2021-03-16 22:59:59
2                <NA>
```